# Cómo hacer que se guarde sólo calibrador.jpg de C:\Users\user\Desktop\calibrador.jpg

Tags: str-replace, img

Desde una computadora `A` que se está conectado desde `IP` a la máquina `B` donde está todo el proyecto,al hacer un registro, en mi `bd` que está en la máquina principal`(B)` si se guarda pero en el campo donde va una imagen se guarda

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\calibrador.jpg
```

Por lo que en la máquina `A` no muestra el resultado en una tabla, sin embargo si modifico el registro dejando solo `calibrador.jpg` si se muestra...

En una function tengo el siguiente código:

```
//Quita toda la ruta sólo dejando el nombre de la imagen
var image = $("#botonSubir").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i,'');
```

Pero el registro que hago desde la máquina A, se guarda en la bd como mencioné anteriormente, con toda la ruta.

Answer (score 1):

con esto tendrás tu problema solucionado.

```
let urlImg = String.raw`C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\calibrador.jpg`.split('\\').join('/')
urlImg = urlImg.split('/')
urlImg = urlImg[urlImg.length-1];
console.log(urlImg);
```

De donde viene esa URL ?
Lo raro es que estes sacando una URL con \ cuando todas funcionan  con / mi código lo que hace es sustituir \ por / antes de que entre en la variable que es cuando te da error.

JS detecta la barra invertida \ como un escape no como un caracter mas, para usar en JS la barra invertida \ se tiene que usar de esta manera var img = 'C:\Users\etc..';

**Edicion**
Si quieres subir ficheros con JS te recomiendo esta guía.
https://ricardogeek.com/como-subir-archivos-con-javascript/

Comment: podrias explicar como funciona tu codigo ? y una breve explicacion del porque ocurre el error ? o en caso que este traducido agregar una referencia ?  una respuesta sin una breve explicacion es considerada de baja calidad por mas que el codigo funcione correctamente

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta.a

Comment: No solo puede ser esa imagen puede ser cualquier otra, esa imagen yo la guarde en escritorio de la maquina A, la que esta conectada por IP, asi no solo puede ser esa. Sin embargo antes de hacer este tipo de pruebas desde otra maquina durante el desarrollo en la maquina B, con la linea de codigo que puse en la pregunta solo guardaba el nombre y la extension. Pero de la otra manera no lo hace.

Comment: De todas maneras si lo que quieres es subir por JS ficheros tendrías que usar $_FILE si no tendrás muchos problemas, edito mi respuesta y te dejo una guia.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es una expresión regular que dada una ruta te deje solo el fichero (sin los directorios anteriores), puedes usar esta:

`^.*[\/\\]`

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/u326Uv/2/)

Y un ejemplo de código aquí:

```js
const ruta = `C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\calibrador.jpg`;
console.log(ruta.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/, ''));
```

De todas formas tampoco considero que esto sea la solución a tu problema.

Entiendo que intentas visualizar una imagen que apunta a `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\calibrador.jpg` lo cual es incorrecto. Un navegador no puede acceder al sistema de ficheros tal que así.

En su lugar, cuando se carga la imagen, ésta se guardar en el servidor web (máquina "B"). Por eso al quitarle la ruta, te funciona.

Ten en cuenta que cuando hagas la carga probablemente necesitarás la ruta completa para poder hacer la carga, pero luego a la hora de visualizar la imagen, el backend devería devolverte donde está alojada.

Es decir, sería algo así:

1. Hay una página web con un formulario para submitir una imagen. La imagen está en el PC del usuario. Por ejemplo en `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\calibrador.jpg`
2. La acción del formulario podría ser una página php, por ejemplo `procesar_formulario.php`
3. En `procesar_formulario.php` guardarás la imagen (por ejemplo en el directorio de la página `B` "imagenes_subidas/calibrador.jpg"
4. Cuando el navegador de la máquina `A` pida la foto, el servidor devería devolverle la ruta donde está alojada, es decir: "imagenes_subidas/calibrador.jpg"

Te dejo una [guía](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) donde se explica (en este caso con php, aunque el concepto sería el mismo para otros lenguajes)